# Нажатие на кнопку в другом приложении

Tags: c#

Всем привет!

**Я хочу автоматизировать заход в майнкрафте (Tlauncher)**, проблема состоит в том, что не могу нажать на кнопку "**Войти в игру**" (через координаты нажать получается). Я пытался найти кнопку в Spy++, но он не видит, он просто всё окно выделяет.

[image: Кнопка - Войти в игру]
Код отчасти рабочий. Приложение видит, а кнопку нет. Читал похожую тему на других форумах, к сожалению некоторые писали, что надо смериться и через координаты мыши, и т.д. Заранее всем огромное спасибо за помощь!

```
        //подключаем поиск окна
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string className, string windowName);

        //подключаем SendMessage
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

```
 //ищем окно по имени
 IntPtr calcWnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "SunAwtFrame", "TLauncher 2.86");

 //ищем в окне calcWnd кнопку класса Button с подписью Войти в игру
 IntPtr button1 = FindWindowEx(calcWnd, IntPtr.Zero, null, "Войти в игру");

 Console.WriteLine(calcWnd != IntPtr.Zero); // вывожу данные true-false
 Console.WriteLine(button1 != IntPtr.Zero);

 if (button1 != IntPtr.Zero)
  SendMessage(button1, 0x00F5, 1, 0); // нажатие на кнопку
```

Comment: Что мешает клиент запустить напрямую без лаунчера?

Comment: @aepot увы, без посредника никак.

Comment: кликайте тогда по координатам

Comment: `без посредника никак` - ох сомневаюсь, этот лаунчер полюбому просто запускает игру с конкретными параметрами, может попутно еще какой-либо процесс (а-ля античит), вот это и эмулируйте, а не пытайтесь автоматизировать UI.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Понял. Постараюсь узнать по этому поводу информацию. Спасибо за помощь